# What kind of algebra and how can I learn its properties

Tags: nonassociative-algebras

I try to find any information on the following algebra defined as:
$$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$$
$$(a,b)*(c,d)=(ac,ac-bd)$$
It is non-associative, but commutative and distributive.
Can it be classified somehow? Do there exist any information on it? How can I find its properties?

Comment: For what it's worth, the components of $(a, b) \ast (c, d)$ are the first components of the componentwise product and the "complex product" $((a, b), (c, d)) \mapsto (a c - b d, a d + b c)$. (Over $\Bbb R$, the complex product is exactly the usual complex multiplication.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're maybe talking about general non-associative algebras (also known as distributive algebras). Commutativity is just then a property that non-associative algebras can have or not have. I don't always trust Wikipedia but [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-associative_algebra) would be a good start. There are some good examples like [Jordan Algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_algebra)